# Installing from Debian's unstable repository

Tags: debian, apt

How do I make apt-get install from Debian's unstable repository?

Comment: Don't mix unstable and stable; if you really want more recent versions , try if `backports.debian.org` has what you want; failing that, try upgrading to testing from stable. Failing *that*, you'd ironically be better off trying to run a completely unstable system than a hodgepodge of stable/unstable -- at the very least, any problems you encounter running the latter will be ignored by anyone you ask for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at apt-pinning. Be very careful or you will find yourself running unstable entirely. On a production system, you probably do not want to do that.

http://www.howtoforge.com/a-short-introduction-to-apt-pinning

Comment: Your link doesn't work, answers should be in full on stack overflow rather than pointing to external documentation

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix stable and unstable packages. Not on a production system, not on your home system, perhaps not even on a random testbed you set up just to see how badly it'd explode.

Look at [backports.debian.org](http://backports.debian.org) for backports to stable of specific packages you may want.

If those are still not as updated as you want, set up a test system and see if the 'testing' tree is stable enough for your purposes and has the software you want.

If that *still* isn't enough, even running a full unstable tree is almost certainly **less** likely to break catastrophically than a hybrid stable/unstable hodgepodge.

Finally, as an absolute last resort, you might want to try downloading the source packages, installing `build-essential` and `devscripts` and then building the packages yourself in the stable system.

Answer (score 0):

Judicious use of apt-get -b source. This allows to handle dependencies more flexibly and does not need dangerous deb lines (just deb-src lines) in sources.list.